# Why is my morse code to english java programming not showing any errors but not printing anything?

Tags: java, morse-code

I'm making a java program that converts morse code to english. I've searched for help, and found that maybe I need to do something with `string.split()`, but I have no experience with it, and don't know where to put it. Here's my code:

```
String r = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the text you would like to be translated into morse code. Use spaces between letters, and \"|\" for a space. " "\n To print \"Hi there\", you would want to type \'.... .. | - .... . .-. . \'\n\n The morse code will print out at the bottom of your screen.");

char [] regenglish = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 
    'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 
    'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', 
    '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '?', '.', ',', '/', ':', ';',
    '-', '"', '\'', '(', ')', ' '};

String[] regmorse = { ".- ", "-... ", "-.-. ", "-.. ", 
    ". ", "..-. ", "--. ", ".... ", ".. ", ".--- ", "-.- ", ".-.. ", "-- ", "-.", 
    "--- ", ".--. ", "--.- ", ".-. ", "... ", "- ", "..- ", "...- ", ".-- ", 
    "-..- ", "-.-- ", "--.. ", "----- ", ".---- ", "..--- ", 
    "...-- ", "....- ", "..... ", "-.... ", "--... ", "---.. ",
    "----. ", "-.-.-- ", "..--.. ", ".-.-.- ", "--..-- ", "-..-. ", "-- -... ",
    "-.-.- ", "-....- ", ".----. ", "-.--. ", "-.--.- ", 
        "| "};

String[] morseChars = r.split(" ");

char[] chars = Arrays.toString(morseChars).toCharArray();
boolean endsWithWordSeparator = Arrays.toString(chars).endsWith("| ");
String st = "";
for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < regmorse.length; i++)
    {
        if (regmorse[i].equals(Character.toString(chars[j]))) 

        {
            st = st + regenglish[i];
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(st);
```

I guess I'm just confused on why this isn't printing anything, and what role 
     `string.split()` plays, if any.

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging it?

Comment: please format the code so it's not hurting the eyes

Comment: As a hint, it would be better to use a HashMap that maps the characters in `regenglish` to their morse code equivalents.

Comment: @newatjava16 I think what lexicore is getting at is that if you use a debugger to step through your code, then you will notice that one of the paths you expect your code to take instead always takes a different path. Your question would then become "Why does this condition always evaluate to false?", which is more focused.

Comment: `Arrays.toString(morseChars)` does not do what you think it does.  It creates a comma-separated list surrounded by brackets.  There are [better ways](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) to concatenate an array of Strings, but in your case, you should have refrained from splitting the string and instead used `r.replace(" ", "")` to remove all spaces.  Then there would be no array and no need to concatenate its elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (regmorse[i].equals(Character.toString(chars[j])))`

You're attempting to compare a character against a multi-character string, so this condition will never be satisfied. For instance, you're checking if "-... " is equivalent to ".".

You need to either compare regmorse character-by-character or package the characters of chars together before comparing them against regmorse.